# How to verify Firebase password reset code with firebase admin SDK?

Tags: firebase-authentication

I know it is possible with the client SDK but is it possible with the admin SDK? The reason I want to do this is because I want my own back-end to verify the code so that I can also send a password reset confirmation email. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Admin SDK does not provide this functionality.  However, you are free to implement a password reset system yourself, using the Admin SDK only to actually change the user's password by [updating the user account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user).

Comment: Is there any reason for this not being possible? It is kind of silly to implement this yourself again when the functionality is already there and you just need a way to interact with it. Is there an API endpoint for this perhaps?

Comment: Ah. Found it! https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-verify-password-reset-code.